# does NSLog work the same as System.out.print in Java?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, nslog

I am migrating from Java to Objective-C, so having a bit easy but meaningful question,

can I do

```
NSLog(@"\n"); // instead of 
System.out.println();
```

and

```
NSLog (@"%i",a); //instead of 
System.out.print(a);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. NSLog prints the message to stderr. The only difference from printf is that it adds some extra info (like time and build name). printf prints to stdout.

Comment: So as Max notes, it's not entirely identical to println since you can't print an "empty" line to the output.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, but not quite. NSLog prints to stderr, *and* to the system log.